# How to concatenate image of multi paths and multi classes

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I modified it from zhihuhao/unet

I want to concatenate 6 GLCM images to perform a UNet classification task.

How can I successfully concatenate images of multi paths?

```
folders = [
    'classes1/glcm1', #7 classes, 42 paths
    'classes1/glcm2',
    'classes1/glcm3',
    'classes1/glcm4',
    'classes1/glcm5', 
    'classes1/glcm6',
    'classes2/glcm1',
        …
    'classes7/glcm6',
]
```

```
def Generator(...)

    for paths in folders:
        image_generator = a.flow_from_directory(...)
        mask_generator = b.flow_from_directory(...)
        
        img = np.concatenate(glcm_list, axis=3)
        mask = np.concatenate(mask_list, axis=3)
        yield (img, mask)
```

I tried use several append then zip,iterator to concatenate & yield but will appear out of memory

by the way, convert mask to one-hot vector in classification task is nesscery?

I found adjustData code,but it seem will affect concatenate mask.

Comment: it appears as though the `np.concatenate()` function is used incorrectly. please provide a reproducable example.  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)